# Is it safe to delete folder com.apple.appstore?

Tags: macos, mac-appstore

I am running extremely low on disk space and trying to clean up my Mac. Disk Inventory X shows me having over 20gb of space in .pkg (installer package) files in 
    `/private/var/folders/pj/_(random)_/C/com.apple.appstore/*`

I am wondering if these are safe to delete (they are in /private after all)? However I really don't want to give up 20 gigabytes to installer files.

Also, is there any built-in way to delete them (meaning through appstore menu or something, not via finder)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is the Download folder for App Store; where it saves apps as it downloads them.

It should be perfectly safe to delete them.

However, I have to say that it is a little strange that the files aren't being deleted automatically, either when you close App Store or when you restart - that is what I would expect. I haven't come across a case where they build up over time.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Neither restarting the computer nor closing the App Store cleans up those files. Deleting the files seems to have no impact on my programs, but I did keep the receipt files behind in case they have something to do with my licensing.

Comment: I had this exact problem, and all leftover files seemed to be identically named XCode installers. It represented around 30GB of data.