# Is it safe to delete the com.apple.appstore folder? It takes up 80gb on my 256gb hard drive

Tags: macos, finder, disk-space

Is it safe to delete this folder? From what I've read, it just holds App Store cache. I'm running really low on disk space, and this folder is **massive**.

Edit:
The filepath is: Macintosh HD/private/var/folders/bw/0tlgj1q56zs3msbssd_w4jv40000gn/C/com.apple.appstore

All the folders inside of it contain a package and a file called preflight.pfpkg.

Edit 2: I took a closer look at the packages inside and it looks like they're all Xcode installers, like every single one of them. I made a Time Machine backup in case something went wrong, but so far it's been smooth sailing.

Comment: what's inside of this folder?  I wouldn't delete the folder but maybe the contents of the folder.

Comment: where is this folder?

Comment: I am at a loss to understand why that folder is so large. I have the same folder on my 10-year-old computer and its at 90 MB. yes MB!  I've never cleaned it out or anything since I just learned of its existence tonight from your question.  And i have a ton of apps on my machine.

Comment: I have 7 folders with that name on my Mac, none over a few MB. You need to tell us precisely which one, where & what is in it.

Comment: Please provide the full path to this folder.

Comment: @benwiggy I've updated the post to include this info, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s safe to delete just about anything as long as you:

1. Have a backup and know how to restore things.
2. Have internet recovery so if you break things, you can reinstall macOS.

Since you know where that folder is located, it’s best to give a general answer since we can’t guess if that’s something you made, another software made or [Apple made](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/71449/5472).

Then feel free to ask a follow on question if you need help like this and you don’t have good results with a process to reset things:

- [Mac App Store Download Failure - Clear Cache?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/171827/5472)

In my experience, this self-solves by booting to recovery, reinstalling the OS and restarting twice, no need to delete anything at all. (But it’s a pretty rare failure in my experience)

Comment: Thanks! I'll make a time machine backup and restore the folder if anything goes wrong.